# Can somebody explain the function of this list comprehension?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a question regarding this following code example. This coding-style is quite advanced and I am trying to get every line. I don't understand the `in_clusters`-array. I think list comprehension is used there. The element `current` is an iterable in the array `current_inds`. But what is `itr in current` doing? Are these like 2 for-loops, or 1-while-loop and 1 for-loop. Is it possible to write this kind of line with simple loops?

```
clusters = []
current_inds = []
itr = 0
for slope, intercept in zip(slopes, intercepts):
        in_clusters = np.array([itr in current for current in current_inds])
        if not in_clusters.any():
            slope_cluster = np.logical_and(slopes < (slope+slope_similarity_threshold), slopes >   (slope-slope_similarity_threshold))
            intercept_cluster = np.logical_and(intercepts < (intercept+intercept_similarity_threshold), intercepts > (intercept-intercept_similarity_threshold))
            
            inds = np.argwhere(slope_cluster & intercept_cluster & slopes_horizontal).T
            if inds.size:
                current_inds.append(inds.flatten())
                clusters.append(lines[inds])
        itr += 1
        
    merged_lines = [np.mean(cluster, axis=1) for cluster in clusters]
    merged_lines = np.array(merged_lines).reshape((-1, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[itr in current for current in current_inds]
```

Let's add a couple of parentheses:

```
[(itr in current) for current in current_inds]
```

Here `itr in current` is the expression which is evaluated & added to the list that's getting created by the comprehension. The rest of the comprehension is just standard.

It's equivalent to:

```
result = []
for current in current_inds:
    if itr in current:
         result.append(True)
    else:
         result.append(False)
```